# PowerShell Office 365 Script to get user and mailbox information together

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

I am brand new to PowerShell (started this morning). I have successfully connected to my Office 365 and have been able to get lists of users from Office 365 and mailbox fields from the Exchange portion. What I can't figure out is how to combine them.

What I am looking for is the ability to export certain fields from the mailbox object but only for those mailboxes that belong to a non-blocked, licensed Office 365 users. We have a lot of users whose mailboxes have not been removed but they may no longer be licensed or they may be blocked.

Here are the two exports I have running now. They are complete exports. I tried to filter to the Office 265 users by isLicensed but I never got any results so I just downloaded everything and post processed them with Excel. But I need to run this on a regular basis...

Here's the code:

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Select-Object DisplayName,Name,PrimarySMTPAddress,CustomAttribute2 | Export-CSV  C:\temp\o365\mailboxes.csv
Get-MsolUser -all | Select-Object SignInName, DisplayName, Office, Department, Title, IsLicensed | export-csv c:\temp\o365\Users.csv
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post what code you have so far? Might make a little more sense if we can specifically see what you're trying to use.

Comment: Just added the code I have. It's pretty basic, I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so as I understand what you're trying to do... You want to get a list of all O365 users for whom the `IsLicensed` property is `$true` and the `BlockCredential` property is `$false`. Of those users, you then want to pull some data from their mailbox objects; DisplayName, Name, PrimarySMTPAddress, and CustomAttribute2.

There are a couple of ways that we can do this. The first is easier to throw together in the shell but takes longer to actually run. The second requires some set up but completes quickly.

### First method

Since we know what our criteria is for what we want from `Get-MsolUser`, we'll use the pipeline to pull out what we want and toss it straight into `Get-Mailbox`.

```
Get-MsolUser -All | Where-Object {$_.IsLicensed -eq $true -and $_.BlockCredential -eq $false} | 
Select-Object UserPrincipalName | 
ForEach-Object {Get-Mailbox -Identity $_.UserPrincipalName | Select-Object DisplayName,Name,PrimarySMTPAddress,CustomAttribute2}
```

O365 PowerShell doesn't like giving us ways to filter our initial query, so we handle that in the second step, here...

`Where-Object {$_.IsLicensed -eq $true -and $_.BlockCredential -eq $false}`

This means, for each item passed in from `Get-MsolUser -All`, we only want those which have the properties `Islicensed` set to $true and `BlockCredential` set to $false.

Now, we only care about the results of `Get-MsolUser` in so far as determining what mailboxes to look up, so we'll grab a single property from each of the objects matching our prior filter.

`Select-Object UserPrincipalName`

If you only run everything up to this point, you'd get a list of UPNs in your shell for all of the accounts that we're now going to pipe into `Get-Mailbox`.

Moving on to our loop in this... If you haven't learned `ForEach-Object` yet, it's used to run a scriptblock (everything between the `{}`) against each item in the pipeline, one at a time.

`Get-Mailbox -Identity $_.UserPrincipalName`

Welcome to the pipeline operator (`$_`). Our previous `Select-Object` is feeding a collection of objects through the pipeline and this placeholder variable will hold each one as we work on them. Since these objects all have a `UserPrincipalName` property, we reference that  for the value to pass to the `Identity` parameter of `Get-Mailbox`.

---

## Sidebar

Here's a simple example of how this works..

```
PS> 1,2,3 | ForEach-Object {Write-Host $_}
1
2
3
```

Each item is passed along the pipeline, where we write them out one at a time. This is very similar to your standard `foreach` loop. You can learn more about their differences in [this Scripting Guy post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/07/08/getting-to-know-foreach-and-foreach-object/).

Moving on...

---

`Select-Object DisplayName,Name,PrimarySMTPAddress,CustomAttribute2`

We wrap it up with one last `Select-Object` for the information that you want. You can then look at the results in the shell or pipe into `Export-Csv` for working with in Excel.

Now... Since the pipeline works sequentially, there's some overhead to it. We're running a command, collecting the results, and then passing those results into the next command one at a time. When we get to our `Get-Mailbox`, we're actually running `Get-Mailbox` once for every UPN that we've collected. This takes about 2.5 minutes in my organization and we have less than 500 mailboxes. If you're working with larger numbers, the time to run this can grow very quickly.

### Second method

Since a large amount of the processing overhead in the first method is with using the pipeline, we can eliminate most of it by handling our data collection as early and thoroughly as possible.

```
$Users = Get-MsolUser -All | Where-Object {$_.IsLicensed -eq $true -and $_.BlockCredential -eq $false} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty UserPrincipalName
$Mailboxes = Get-Mailbox | Select-Object UserPrincipalName,DisplayName,Name,PrimarySMTPAddress,CustomAttribute2

$Results = foreach ($User in $Users) {
    $Mailboxes | Where-Object UserPrincipalName -eq $User
}

$Results | Export-Csv myFile.csv
```

The first 2 lines are pretty self-explanatory. We get all the user account info that we care about (just the UPNs) and then we grab all the mailbox properties that we care about.

`foreach ($User in $Users)`

Each entry in `$Users` will be stored in `$User`, where we'll then use it in the scriptblock that follows (in the `{}`).

`$Mailboxes | Where-Object UserPrincipalName -eq $User`

Each item in `$Mailboxes` is piped into `Where-Object` where we then check if the `UserPrincipalName` property is equal to the current value of `$User`. All of the matches are then stored in `$Results`, which can again be piped to `Export-Csv` for work in Excel.

While this method is harder to write out in the shell, and requires a little extra initial set up, it runs significantly faster; 22 seconds for my org, versus 2.5 minutes with the first method.

I should also point out that the use of `UserPrincipalName` with the mailbox dataset is simply to help ensure a solid match between those and the account dataset. If you don't want it in your final results, you can always pipe `$Results` into another `Select-Object` and specify only the properties that you care about.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I do have one question. Suppose I want to add some columns from $User into my result set? For example, if I want the title, department, etc...? Can I do this with the second method?

Comment: Off the top of my head, not without reworking how either example works. In both cases, we're only returning mailbox data. The user data is only used to help determine which mailboxes to look at. However, Warren Frame has an excellent PowerShell function called `Join-Object` that you can learn about [here](http://ramblingcookiemonster.github.io/Join-Object/). It lets you join two sets of data on a similar unique value (i.e. UserPrincipalName) just like a SQL join. That's where I'd start.

Comment: Awesome explanation!